# ¿Es posible tener dos modulos de angularjs en una sola página de html, si eso se puede, cual es la manera correcta de ejecutar ambos modulos?

Tags: angularjs

Mi duda es cual es la manera correcta de ejecutar dos modulos de angularjs en un solo html, sucede que tengo una página maestra y esta ejecuta un controlador de un modulo y en otra página ejecuto otro controlador de otro modulo, pero por alguna razón el segundo controlador no es ejecutado

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - Mi aplicación ASP.NET</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
<body class="ColorPagina">
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" style="background-color:#06a2f1">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <img src="http://sysweb.unach.mx/resources/imagenes/logo_sysweb_b.png" />
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>

            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" ng-app="MenuWeb" ng-controller="MenuController as mnu">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="dropdown mega-dropdown" ng-repeat="menu in mnu.SiteMenu">
                        <a href="{{menu.ID}}" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">{{menu.NOMBRE}} <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu mega-dropdown-menu">
                            <li class="dropdown-header">{{menu.NOMBRE}}</li>
                            <li class="col-sm-3" ng-repeat="item in menu.SubMenu track by $index">
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="{{item.CONTROL_NOMBRE}}">{{item.NOMBRE}}</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#">My cart (0) items</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>  
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer class="footer" style="background-color:#252727">
            <img src="http://sysweb.unach.mx/resources/imagenes/imgfooter.png" style="width:900px; height:83px" />
        </footer>
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

    <script src="~/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/global.js"></script>
    
    <script src="~/Scripts/Models/MenuModel.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/Controllers/MenuController.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

```html
<body >
    <div class="divConteiner" ng-app="SolicitudesWeb" >        
        <div class="tab">
            <button type="button" class="tablinks btn btn-primary" onclick="siguiente(event, 'Paso1')">Paso 1</button>
            <button type="button" class="tablinks btn btn-primary" onclick="siguiente(event, 'Paso2')">Paso 2</button>
        </div>
        
        <div   id="Paso1" ng-controller="SolicitudController as ctrl" class="container-fluid divPrincipal">
            <div class="panel panel-white">
                <div class="row ColorPaginaDiv">
                    <div ng-controller="ObtenerListaComprasController as ctrlCompras" class="panel-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <p>Tipo de Compra</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <div>
                                    <select  class="form-control" name="cmbTipoCompra" id="cmbTipoCompra" ng-change="ValorCompra()" ng-options="option.Id as option.Descripcion for option in ctrlCompras.Compra" ng-model="ctrlCompras.TipoCompra"></select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <p>Fecha solicitud: </p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <input type="text" id="fecha" name="fecha" ng-model="ctrl.calendario"/>                                
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <p>Dependencia: </p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-8" ng-controller="ObtenerListaDependenciasController as ctrlDependencia">
                                <select class="form-control" name="cmbDependencia" id="cmbDependencia" ng-change="ValorDependencia()" ng-options="option.Id as option.Descripcion for option in ctrlDependencia.Dependencias" ng-model="ctrlDependencia.Dependencia"></select>                            
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div ng-controller="ObtenerProgramasController as ctrlProgramas" class="panel-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <p>Programas: </p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <select class="form-control" name="cmbProgramas" id="cmbProgramas" ng-change="ValorPrograma()" ng-options="option.Id as option.Descripcion for option in ctrlProgramas.Programas" ng-model="ctrlProgramas.TipoPrograma"></select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="DivText">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <p>Objetivo del Proyecto: </p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                    <textarea class="StyleText" name="txtObjProyecto" required ng-model="ctrl.objetivoProyecto"></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="DivText">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <p>Justificacion: </p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                    <textarea class="StyleText" name="txtJustificacion" ng-model="ctrl.justificacion"></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="DivText">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <p>Lugar de Entrega: </p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                    <textarea class="StyleText" name="txtLugarEntrega" ng-model="ctrl.lugarEntrega"></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <p>Responsable Proyecto: </p>
                            </div>
                            <div ng-controller="ObtenerResponsablesController as ctrlObtenerResponsables" class="col-md-8">
                                <select class="form-control" name="cmbResponsable" id="cmbResponsable" ng-change="ValorResponsable()" ng-options="option.Id as option.Descripcion for option in ctrlObtenerResponsables.Responsables" ng-model="ctrlObtenerResponsables.ResponsableProyecto"></select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="DivText">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <p>Comentarios: </p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                    <textarea class="StyleText" name="txtComentarios" ng-bind="ctrl.comentarios" ng-model="ctrl.comentarios"></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            <input type="button" value="Continuar" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ctrl.GuardarDatos()"/>  
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="Cancelar" onclick = "location='/Home/Contact'"/>
                        </div>                        
                    </div>
                    <div class="alert alert-danger avisoError" role="alert">
                        {{ctrl.ResultadoError}}
                    </div>
                </div>                
            </div>
        </div>      

        <div id="Paso2" class="divPrincipal" ng-controller="SolicitudesDetalleController as ctrlSolicitudDetalle">
            <div>
                <button type="button" class="tablinks btn btn-primary" onclick="mostrarDetalle();">Detalle</button>
                <button type="button" class="tablinks btn btn-primary" onclick="mostrarGrid();">Datos Generales</button>
            </div>
            <table class="table table-striped" id="tablaDetalle" style="display:block">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Lote</th>
                        <th>Cantidad</th>
                        <th>Producto</th>
                        <th>Importe</th>
                        <th>Iva</th>
                        <th>Total</th>
                        <th>Editar</th>
                        <th>Eliminar</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="x in ctrlSolicitudDetalle.SolicitudesDetalle">
                        <td>{{x.Id}}</td>
                        <td>{{x.Lote}}</td>
                        <td>{{x.Cantidad}}</td>
                        <td>{{x.Producto}}</td>
                        <td>{{x.Importe}}</td>
                        <td>{{x.Iva}}</td>
                        <td>{{x.Total}}</td>
                        <td><i ng-click="ctrlSolicitudDetalle.Prueba()" class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
                        <td><i ng-click="ctrlSolicitudDetalle.Prueba()" class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>

            <div id="descripcion" class="panel panel-white" style="display:none">
                <div class="row ColorPaginaDiv">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <p>Codigo Programatico</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                <div ng-controller="ObtenerListaCodigoProgramaticoController as ctrlObtenerCodigoProg">
                                    <select class="form-control" name="cmbCodigoProg" id="cmbCodigoProg" ng-options="option.Id as option.Descripcion for option in ctrlObtenerCodigoProg.ListaCodigoProgramatico" ng-model="ctrlObtenerCodigoProg.CodigoProgramatico"></select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <p>Monto Autorizado</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div ng-controller="">
                                    <input />
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <p>Monto Disponible</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div ng-controller="">
                                    <input />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <p>Lote</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div ng-controller="">
                                    <input />
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <p>Cantidad</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div ng-controller="">
                                    <input />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <p>Unidad</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div ng-controller="">
                                    <input />
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <p>Sub-total: $</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div ng-controller="">
                                    <input />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <p>I.V.A: $</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div ng-controller="">
                                    <input />
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <p>Total: $</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div ng-controller="">
                                    <input />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <p>Producto</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                <div ng-controller="">
                                    <select class="form-control" name="cmbProducto" id="cmbProducto" @*ng-options="option.Descripcion for option in ctrl3.Compra track by option.Id" ng-model="ctrl3.TipoCompra"*@></select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <p>No. de Dictamen</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div ng-controller="">
                                    <input />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="DivText">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <p>Descripcion: </p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-10">
                                    <textarea class="StyleText" name="txtDescripcion" required></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <p>Categor&iacute;a</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                <div ng-controller="">
                                    <select class="form-control" name="cmbCategoria" id="cmbCategoria" @*ng-options="option.Descripcion for option in ctrl3.Compra track by option.Id" ng-model="ctrl3.TipoCompra"*@></select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="DivText">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <p>Caracteristicas minimas requeridas por C.T.I. </p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-10">
                                    <textarea class="StyleText" name="txtCTI" required></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <input type="checkbox"> Sin Enlazar
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <strong><p>Documentos Requeridos</p></strong>
                                <input id="cbDR1" type="checkbox"> DICTAMEN PARA ADQ DE EQUIPOS DE COMUNICACIONES, TELECOMUNICACIONES E INFORMATICOS<br />
                                <input id="cbDR2" type="checkbox"> DICTAMEN PARA ADQUISICIONES DE EQUIPOS DE AIRES ACONDICIONADOS <br />
                                <input id="cbDR3" type="checkbox"> EN TODOS LOS CASOS OFICIO DE AUTORIZACIÓN DE RECURSO <br />
                                <input id="cbDR4" type="checkbox"> ANEXAR IMPRESIÓN A COLOR Y LA ESCALA, EN CASO DE REQUERIR LOGOTIPOS O SIMILARES <br />
                                <input id="cbDR5" type="checkbox"> DICTAMEN PARA ADQUISICIÓN DE VEHICULOS Y MAQUINARIA PESADA <br />
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <strong><p>Informaci&oacute;n Requerida</p></strong>
                                <input id="cmbIR1" type="checkbox"> PRESENTACIÓN DE MUESTRAS<br />
                                <input id="cmbIR2" type="checkbox"> CATALOGOS <br />
                                <input id="cmbIR3" type="checkbox"> GARANTIAS <br />
                                <input id="cmbIR4" type="checkbox"> DISEÑOS Y LOGOTIPOS <br />
                                <input id="cmbIR5" type="checkbox"> SE REQUIERE DE INSTALACIÓN, MANTENIMIENTO, ASISTENCIA TÉCNICA <br />
                                <input id="cmbIR6" type="checkbox"> SE REQUIERE DE NORMAS OFICIALES <br />
                                <input id="cmbIR7" type="checkbox"> ENTREGA LIBRE A BORDO EN ESTABLECIMIENTO DEL PROVEEDOR <br />
                                <input id="cmbIR8" type="checkbox"> CALENDARIO DE ENTREGA <br />
                                <input id="cmbIR9" type="checkbox"> SE REQUIERE DE VISITAS FISICAS <br />
                                <input id="cmbIR10" type="checkbox"> CRITERIOS DE ASIGNACION PROPUESTO <br />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
    </div> 
    
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quizás al momento de inyectar en el "ng-modules" te falte:

```
ng-modules="MyModuleA, MyModuleB"
```

Si quieres usar un solo módulo:

```
ng-module="MyModuleB"
```

Comment: edité mi pregunta, los modulos los agrego con ng-app, pero no se si esa es la manera correcta

Comment: @RafaRosales en angular solo puede existir un ng-app con un solo módulo, te recomiendo que hagas un módulo donde "conectes" el resto de módulos, mira esto: 

[http://www.simplygoodcode.com/2014/04/angularjs-getting-around-ngapp-limitations-with-ngmodule/]

Comment: @RafaRosales y respondiendo a tu pregunta: Es correcto, pero solo un módulo.

Comment: Muchas gracias! Es lo que estaba buscando!

Comment: @RafaRosales recuerda chekearla si es la respuesta que esperabas.